# Letsencrypt Stage PEM with fszlin/certes

Tags: c#, lets-encrypt, pem, acme

I'm using fszlin/certes to generate LE certificates.

I've downloaded the latest staging issuer PEM from Lets Encrypt and converted it to a Base64 String.

```
byte[] base64PEM = Convert.FromBase64String(lePemContents);
```

However, when I attempt to add using:

```
pfxbuilder.AddIssuers(base64PEM);
```

and "building" the PFX, I'm getting an error:

> "Can not find issuer 'C=US,O=(STAGING) Internet Security Research Group,CN=(STAGING) Doctored Durian Root CA X3' for certificate 'C=US,O=(STAGING) Let's Encrypt,CN=(STAGING) Artificial Apricot R3'."

Does this PEM have to be encoded in some special way for the pfxbuilder to build correctly and not return this error?

I have downloaded an encoded version (.cer) which does work from a third party, however, I'd like to use the PEM from LetsEncrypt so, should LE change it again, the code is set up to do the conversion without any third party involved.

I've also tried

```
lePemContents = lePemContents.Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "");
lePemContents = lePemContents.Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "");
lePemContents = lePemContents.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Before the

```
Convert.FromBase64String(lePemContents);
```

with the same result.

What might I be missing?
TIA

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post and I assume long since solved, but for the benefit of anyone else struggling with this issue, you can use File.ReadAllBytes to load the Let'sEncrypt PEM file directly:

```
byte[] issuerPem =  File.ReadAllBytes("issuerPem.pem");
pfxbuilder.AddIssuers(issuerPem);
```